# How can you be notified of DynamicResource changes (relative to a particular FrameworkElement) without having a DependencyProperty to set it on?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, behavior, dynamicresource

Have an odd request.  I need to be notified when a dynamic resource changes relative to a FrameworkElement, but I'm not setting a property *on* that FrameworkElement.  As such, I can't use `{DynamicResource someKey}` in XAML, nor `someElement.SetResourceReference()` in code-behind.

Now getting the current value is easy.  You just call `someElement.FindResource("someKey")` and you get whatever the current value is, but that requires polling.

I considered creating a faux binding source object that I could then bind to, but the problem there is it's not part of the visual tree so unless that resource is defined at the app level, you won't get it.  You can't just jam stuff into the visual tree either.

I've seen an answer that uses Behaviors which can define a DependencyProperty, and when attached to the FrameworkElement, they do update as one would suspect, but that requires XAML since I don't know how to call the Behaviors-equivalent of FrameworkElement's setResourceReference.

So... thoughts?

Comment: Why would you need such a thing ? Are you sure that the resource is the way to go ?

Comment: lol... I love when people comment on the usage rather than the question. Yes, it has to be a resource.  I over-simplified it to get at the core information I need, which is being able to bind to a Dynamic Resource and feed it through a converter.  I actually found a solution in the form of a DynamicResourceExtension where in the ProvideValue I get the base value from ProvideValue(), set that as the value of a Dp of type object on a custom Behavior, add the behavior to the target framework element's behaviors, then also use it as the source of a binding where I set the converter and return.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a satisfying answer without the usage. The Behavior A.K.A attached property solution will work but it uses a `DependencyProperty`.

```
public static class AttachedProperty
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DynamicResourceProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DynamicResource", typeof(object), typeof(AttachedProperty), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static object GetDynamicResource(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (object)obj.GetValue(DynamicResourceProperty);
    }

    public static void SetDynamicResource(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(DynamicResourceProperty, value);
    }
}
```

You set the attached property on the Element you want to track the resource for.

```
<Grid x:Name="grid" my:AttachedProperty.DynamicResource="{DynamicResource Brush}"/>
```

And that is a `DependecyProperty` you can bind to, get notifications and pass the value to converters.

Comment: Not quite. After all, what do you bind that property to where you use the converter?  You need another object as the target with its own dependency property, using this one as the source.  Plus, you'd have to create different Attached Properties for each such usage.  (i.e. you can't have two dynamic resource bindings on the same object this way.)  While my Behavior solution does new up such objects internally, all that is hidden from the user who uses it just like a regular binding.  I'll post my solution once it gets cleaned up more.

Comment: I didn't, but i agree this is not a good question, post the usage in the code form, and when it becomes clear what you trying to do and the question can serve other users i will upvote it.